# Publish shapefile cannot be previewed

Tags: geoserver

When published the shapefile, I can not preview it on GeoServer's Layer Preview with default page size. But, if change the width to 1900, then i can see it. However, the map can not zoom out, and can not see the entire map, too.

I just learned GeoServer, and I don't know what went wrong, but I think it should be caused by the configuration.

The shapefile is [line.zip](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/guojing7/shapefiles/main/line.zip).

Comment: What does the log file show?

Comment: Since it has no projection.. which EPSG code did you choose in the layer configuration UI?

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the problem but I suspect the issue is the shapefile, it has no projection and all the data is on the extreme left of the extent so I suspect that GeoServer is confused by trying to scale an unprojected file in the preview window.